# Unit testing a Library and API - How NOT to Repeat Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

At the moment we're struggling with structuring our code so that it doesn't get repeated.

A sample test:

```
describe('#getSentence()', function() {
    it('should start with an uppercase character', function() {
        let fChar = ipsumGenerator.getSentence().slice(0, 1);

        fChar.should.be.equal(
            fChar.toUpperCase()
        );
    });
});
```

For now, we're just omitting the test as described below, and only validate whether a valid JSON object is returned. We do that because when the specification changes, we otherwise have to adjust 2 tests, but that ensures that we're only able to validate the API visually by hand.

```
describe('GET /api/ipsum/lorem/sentence/yes', function() {
    it('should return a valid json object', function(whenDone) {
        request(expressApp).get(uriPath)
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(withError, res) {
                if (withError) return whenDone(withError);

                //
                // Repeating Code:
                let fChar = res.body.s.slice(0, 1);

                fChar.should.be.equal(
                    fChar.toUpperCase()
                );
                //
                // End of Repeating Code

                whenDone();
            );
        });
    });
});
```

Is there a "proper" way to omit the repeating code?

Comment: Repeating code within tests can be a smell: it often shows up when you're testing too deep and end up validating some other module's code. That could be a problem with your tests, where they overlap a lot or you're getting too far into the results, or a problem with the code, where it is not modular enough and you're testing too many layers at once.

Comment: We could only validate the library and leave the API testing alone, but should we? As we want to be sure that the object returned from the API is the one requested as given by the library which is already tested.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing [a larger type of test](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2010/12/test-sizes.html), which will have a lot of duplicate code. In my experience, we write (and small/unit test) a supporting library for common med/large test tasks, like logging in.